# PHP Predefined Constant SID Causing Memory/Overflow Issue

Tags: php, prado

I'm calling the constructUrl method within the THttpRequest class of the PRADO Framework (v3.2.2) using PHP 5.4.45.

The method contains the following line of code:

```
if(defined('SID') && SID != '' && !$this->_cookieOnly)
```

The PHP predefined constant SID is intermittently causing one of the following errors:

- **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1109415573 bytes)**. Using memory_get_usage directly before this line of code returns only 13329624 bytes.
- **Fatal error: String size overflow**

The method is called in a loop to output 20 table rows of hyperlinks. var_export(SID) within the previous loops before failure returns an empty string. The errors do not occur on every page load - it appears totally random although the user actions on the page are exactly the same.

I expect SID to be empty. Any ideas as to what could cause this issue?

Comment: Well either your data is so big that you need to increase the maximum memory size. Or you have a endless recursion/loop which adds something to a string (which we do not see here) or (in case of the recursion) your function overhead is too high. We cant tell you what the issue is with the provided code, since we do not see much. Provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The data is minimal with only 20 integer IDs selected from the database and the loop is not endless - otherwise the issue would be consistent. Using memory_get_usage, I've identified that the request is using 13329624 before the SID call - then whilst making the SID call the memory jumps to 1109415573 as in the error message. The SID call is inside the Framework - This code has been running for 5 years, so I think it could be some kind of server setting?